# Gather the data with similar columns

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

I want to filter the data from a text file in unix.
I have text file  in unix as  below:

```
A 200
B 300
C 400
A 100
B 600
B 700
```

How could i modify/create data as below from the above data i have  in awk?

```
A 200 100
B 300 600 700
C 400
```

i am not that much good in awk and i believe awk/perl is best for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'END {
  for (R in r) 
    print R, r[R]
  }
{
  r[$1] = $1 in r ? r[$1] OFS $2 : $2
  }' infile
```

If the order of the values in the first field is important,
more code will be needed. 
The solution will depend on your *awk* implementation and version.

Explanation:

```
r[$1] = $1 in r ? r[$1] OFS $2 : $2
```

Set the value of the array r element $1 to:

- if the key $1 is already present: $1 in r, append OFS $2 
  to the existing value
- otherwise set it to the value of $2

expression ? if true : if false is the ternary operator.
See [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) for more.

Comment: could you please also explain the line `r[$1] = $1 in r ? r[$1] OFS $2 : $2`

Comment: Hi @peter, I've added an explanation.

Comment: First guess: you're on Solaris. If that's the case, you sould use nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, instead of /usr/bin/awk.

Comment: Right guess...exactly i am on solaris.since i downvoted earlier.i am accepting your answer even though the other answers are also correct.using nawk solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this, but with Perl there's always more than one way to do it:

```
my %hash; 
while(<>) { 
    my($letter, $int) = split(" "); 
    push @{ $hash{$letter} }, $int;
} 

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    print "$key " . join(" ", @{ $hash{$key} }) . "\n";
}
```

Should work like that:

```
$ cat data.txt | perl script.pl
A 200 100
B 300 600 700
C 400
```

Comment: The one liner: `perl -i.bk -e 'my %rows; while (<>) { chomp; if ($_ ne ""){ my ($id, $value) = split(); print "$id $value\n"; push (@{$rows{$id}}, $value); }} foreach (keys %rows){print $_ . " @{$rows{$_}}\n"; }' data.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Not language-specific. More like pseudocode, but here's the idea :

```
- Get all lines in an array
- Set a target dictionary of arrays

- Go through the array :
       - Split the string using ' '(space) as the delimiter, into array parts
       - If there is already a dictionary entry for `parts[0]` (e.g. 'A'). 
         If not create it.
       - Add `parts[1]` (e.g. 100) to `dictionary(parts[0])`
```

And that's it! :-)

I'd do it, probably in Python, but that's rather a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, sorting the output inside it:

```
awk '
  { data[$1] = (data[$1] ? data[$1] " " : "") $2 } 
  END { 
    for (i in data) { 
      idx[++j] = i 
    } 
    n = asort(idx); 
    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) { 
      print idx[i] " " data[idx[i]] 
    } 
  }
' infile
```

Using external program `sort`:

```
awk '
  { data[$1] = (data[$1] ? data[$1] " " : "") $2 } 
  END { 
    for (i in data) { 
      print i " " data[i] 
    } 
  }
' infile | sort
```

For both commands output is:

```
A 200 100
B 300 600 700
C 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## First line. Newline will separate data, so add it after the content.
## Save it in 'hold space' and read next one.
1 {
    s/$/\n/
    h   
    b   
}

## Append content of 'hold space' to current line.
G

## Search if first char (\1) in line was saved in 'hold space' (\4) and add 
## the number (\2) after it.
s/^\(.\)\( *[0-9]\+\)\n\(.*\)\(\1[^\n]*\)/\3\4\2/

## If last substitution succeed, goto label 'a'.
ta

## Here last substitution failed, so it is the first appearance of the
## letter, add it at the end of the content.
s/^\([^\n]*\n\)\(.*\)$/\2\1/

## Label 'a'.
:a

## Save content to 'hold space'.
h

## In last line, get content of 'hold space', remove last newline and print.
$ {
    x   
    s/\n*$//
    p   
}
```

Run it like:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

And result:

```
A 200 100
B 300 600 700
C 400
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sort -sk1,1 file | sed ':a;$!N;s/^\([^ ]*\)\( .*\)\n\1/\1\2/;ta;P;D'
A 200 100
B 300 600 700
C 400
```